# Отменить выделение текста при двойном щелчке

Tags: jquery

Есть счётчик, если щёлкать быстро, то выделяется текст, что не есть эстетично, как отменить выделение?

```js
$('.minus').click(function() {
  var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
  var count = parseInt($input.val()) - 1;
  count = count < 1 ? 1 : count;
  $input.val(count);
  $input.change();
  return false;
});
$('.plus').click(function() {
  var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
  $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) + 1);
  $input.change();
  return false;
});
```

```css
.counter {
  width: 90px;
  margin-top: 64px;
}

.counter a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  color: #666666;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 3px;
}

.counter input {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 38px;
  height: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="counter cl">
  <a class="plus">+</a>
  <input type="text" value="1">
  <a class="minus">&ndash;</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

используйте css

```
.text {
    user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: Добавил к .counter a это свойство но ничего не поменялось.

Comment: у меня поменялось, а у вас нет?

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RQoNNd

Comment: не забывайте про префиксы
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 -o-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;

Comment: Спасибо помогло.